# Crontab task and email attachment not sent

Tags: php, cron

I made a PHP script yesterday which send an email with a PDF as an attachment.

When I make a crontab with this script shedulded, I recieve the email but not the attachment.
When I launch the script manually, I have the email and the attachment.

Here is the PHP code of the sendMail function :

```
function sendMail()
{
            $corpse = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/output/output.tpl');
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->isMail();
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->From='SenderMailAddress';
            $mail->FromName='SenderName';
            $mail->AddAddress('MyEmail');
            $date = date("Ymd", time());
            $yesterday = date("Ymd", strtotime("-1 day"));
            if ($this->type == cur)
                    $pj = "/opt/birt/ReportEngine/output/bookingperiod_".$date.".pdf";
            else
                    $pj = "/opt/birt/ReportEngine/output/bookingperiod_".$yesterday.".pdf";
            echo $pj;
            $mail->AddAttachment($pj);
            $mail->AddReplyTo('NoReplyAddress');
            $mail->Subject='SubjectOfTheMail';
            $mail->Body=$corpse;
            if (!$mail->Send())
                    echo "Error Sending: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
            unset($mail);
}
```

The script that I put as a crontask :

```
TODAY=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`

export BIRT_HOME=/opt/birt
echo $TODAY

cd /opt/birt/ReportEngine
php GenPeriod.php PDF $TODAY /*first generation of a PDF file which will be the attachment for the PHP script*/

cd MY_PATH_TO_PHPSCRIPT_FOLDER
php Launche.php cur
```

Do someone already encounter the same type of problem ?

How can you solve it ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: The problem is probably somewhere in your code.

Comment: And how can you explain that it works great when I launch it manually ?

Comment: Differing user permissions, for example.

Comment: You really should include some code if you want anyone to verify it for you. However, you might be using a relative path to your file. Add the file path to the your email (subject or body) and verify that its correct. Also make sure the user that runs the script from crontab has sufficient access rights.

Comment: Show some code so people don't have to speculate.

Comment: done, i put some code in the subject. The user that runs the script from crontab is root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this and continue with verifing file permissions.

```
function sendMail()
{
        $corpse = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/output/output.tpl');
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isMail();
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->From='SenderMailAddress';
        $mail->FromName='SenderName';
        $mail->AddAddress('MyEmail');
        $date = date("Ymd", time());
        $yesterday = date("Ymd", strtotime("-1 day"));
        if ($this->type == cur)
                $pj = "/opt/birt/ReportEngine/output/bookingperiod_".$date.".pdf";
        else
                $pj = "/opt/birt/ReportEngine/output/bookingperiod_".$yesterday.".pdf";
        //echo $pj;

        $mail->Subject = (is_readable($pj)) ? 'The file is readable' : 'The file is NOT readable'; // DEBUG

        $mail->AddAttachment($pj);
        $mail->AddReplyTo('NoReplyAddress');
        //$mail->Subject='SubjectOfTheMail';
        $mail->Body=$corpse;
        if (!$mail->Send())
                echo "Error Sending: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
        unset($mail);
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The file was not readable in the current folder. Then I moved it to the /tmp folder with 755 rights and everything's working fine now !

Answer (score 1):

One of the main differences between running a PHP file from command-line and by requesting it from the webserver, is the current directory.

It's a common mistake to forget about it, so I'd try `chdir(dirname(__FILE__).'/');` at the top of your file.

If that's not the problem, show some code, run it with all errors enabled and check its output (of the cronjob).

Comment: That didn't solve the problem. I put some code in the subject.

Comment: Your next step is to localize the problem. The code you've posted looks ok to me, so your problem must be somewhere else. Once again, see if it generates any errors while executing (the output of a cronjob is sent to the users local mail box). Also another good start might be to check if your other script really generates a report in the right place. It's all about limiting potential problem sources.

Comment: I solved the problem by moving the pdf generated by the other script in the /tmp folder. Everything's working fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Missing $-sign in front of MY_PATH_TO_PHPSCRIPT_FOLDER in cron job script.